# How can I decode when I don't know the type, with class inheritance?

Tags: swift, inheritance, swift4, codable

I have a base class `Action`, which is an `Operation`. It has a bunch of crufty `Operation` stuff in it (KVO and all that). The base class itself doesn't actually need to encode/decode anything.

```
class Action : Operation, Codable {
    var _executing = false
    ...
}
```

I have a bunch of `Action` sub-classes, like `DropboxUploadAction`, which are directly instantiated with an `Input` struct they define:

```
let actionInput = DropboxUploadAction.Input.init(...)
ActionManager.shared.run(DropboxUploadAction.init(actionInput, data: binaryData), completionBlock: nil)
```

Here's what the subclasses look like:

```
class DropboxUploadAction : Action {
    struct Input : Codable {
        var guid: String
        var eventName: String
        var fileURL: URL?
        var filenameOnDropbox: String
        var share: Bool
    }

    struct Output : Codable {
        var sharedFileLink: String?
        var dropboxPath: String?
    }

    var input: Input
    var output: Output

    ...

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        input = try values.decode(Input.self, forKey: .input)
        output = try values.decode(Output.self, forKey: .output)
        let superDecoder = try values.superDecoder()
        try super.init(from: superDecoder)
    }

    fileprivate enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case input
        case output
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(input, forKey: .input)
        try container.encode(output, forKey: .output)
        try super.encode(to: container.superEncoder())
    }
}
```

When some situations occur such as a loss of internet connectivity, these classes need to be serialized to disk for later. That's fine, because at the time I have references to them and can encode them with `JSONEncoder().encode(action)`, no problem.

**But later when I want to deserialize them,** I need to specify the type of the class and I don't know what it is. I have some data and I know it can be decoded to a class that inherits from `Action`, but I don't know which subclass it is. I'm loathe to encode that in the filename. Is there some way to decode it as the base class `Action`, then in the `decode()` method of `Action`, somehow detect the proper class and redirect?

In the past I've used `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass()` to handle this. But I don't know how to do that with Swift 4's `Codable`, and I understand that NSCoding is deprecated now so I shouldn't use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` anymore...

If it helps: I have a `struct Types : OptionSet, Codable` which each subclass returns, so I don't have to use the name of the class as its identity.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here's 1 approach that works, but I don't like it because it's ugly: https://gist.github.com/xaphod/3fda8e584dd840e3a3564da8a5b25846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhh `NSCoding` isn't deprecated. We still use it when instantiating UIViewControllers from storyboard via `init(coder:)`.

Also, if you still don't want to use `NSCoding`, you can just store the `Input`,  `Output` and `Types` to a struct and serialize that to disk instead.

```
struct SerializedAction {
  let input: Input
  let output: Output
  let type: Type
}
```

When needed, you can decode that and decide the correct `Action` to initialize with your input/output via the `type` property.

```
class DropboxAction: Action {
  ...
  init(input: Input, output: Output) {
  ...
  }
}
```

You don't necessarily need to encode the entire `Action` object.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I did already come to the same conclusion (encoded only the input), so i'll accept this as the answer